# Is onDraw() necessary in SurfaceView?

Tags: android, view, surfaceview, difference

I refer many sites and also the documentation of Android,but i still having confusion on that,

is `onDraw()` method is necessary in both `View` and `SurfaceView`.

Can some one explains me that how to draw any thing in `View` and `SurfaceView` when using `onDraw()` and without using onDraw() method ?

Thank you.

Comment: yes in both case you can draw by overriding onDraw() method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `SurfaceView` is not necessary, in `View` it is because is your chance to get a reference to the canvas, so you can add extra shapes/Bitmaps to the view, however surface view has a powerful complementary class, `SurfaceHolder` which has a `lockCanvas` method that returns a reference to the canvas of the surface view (without having to override `onDraw`) and most importantly, using `lockCanvas` you can do all the drawing and processing of your shapes/bitmaps **ASYNCHRONOUSLY**(with `unlockCanvasAndPost` to publish your changes), unlike `onDraw` which depends on the main thread and invalidation of the view to be executed...

Hope it helps.

Regards